# How to block a div when arriving at the top of the window during a page scroll

Tags: jquery, css

On an internet browser, I would like to have a div (typically a menu or an information bar) that stops moving when reaching the top of the screen during a page scroll. Note that I do not whant this 'div' to be stuck at one position all the time : It is a normal 'div' that follows page scrolling except when reaching the top of the screen.
I am not sure it can be done only with css, if not, may be you could help me with jquery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery waypoints to help you out with this http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements

With waypoints you can listen in on window scroll events an optionally change the css dynamically to position:fixed when that div hits the top of your screen when you start scrolling down and vice versa when it gets back to its original position when scrolling up.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin works pretty well.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat

http://jsbin.com/eqihef